# XPath find tag contains and then get the span tag below

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I am new to XPath and wouder how to get the `<span>` tag in this HTML code.

I am using the tag contains feature. I match the right tag, but I dont know how to get the `<span>` tag below the `<em>` so that I can get the date:

```
//em[contains(text(), "Datum för upprättande:")]


<li class="clear">
  <em class="">Datum för upprättande:</em>
  <span class="">19-11-2008</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `following-sibling` axis

```
//em[contains(text(), "Datum för upprättande:")]/following-sibling::span
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. following-sibling::span, so if the li tag should have em,span, and lets say address I could change the 
following-sibling::span to following-sibling::address since them em and span and address are siblings right ?

Answer (score 0):

As you specified Nokogiri:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<li class="clear">
<em class="">Datum för upprättande:</em>
<span class="">19-11-2008</span>                                                                                                                                                     
</li>'  

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)                                                                                                                                                           
em = doc.xpath('//em[contains(text(), "Datum för upprättande:")]')                                                                                                                   
puts em[0].next_element.content # => 19-11-2008
```

Comment: This was interesting. Thank you

Comment: Use `at` or `at_xpath` and you don't have to use `em[0]`. `em` by itself would work as it would only contain a single Node, instead of being a NodeSet.